# Checkbox and label in same line

Tags: css, reactjs

I would like to make filters using a modal window. But I have a problem, in that the checkbox and the label appear on different lines.

But I would like to see the checkbox and the label on the same line with a little space between. Tell me how this can be done. My code is below.

```
export default function FilterMethod  () {
    const [methods, setMethods] = useState([]);

    const onMethodChange = (e) => {
        let selectedMethods = [...methods];

        if (e.checked)
            selectedMethods.push(e.value);
        else
            selectedMethods.splice(selectedMethods.indexOf(e.value), 1);

        setMethods(selectedMethods);
    }

    return (

            <div>
                <h6>Method</h6>
                <div>
                    <Checkbox inputId="method1" name="method" value="Connect" onChange={onMethodChange} checked={methods.indexOf('Connect') !== -1} />
                    <label htmlFor="method1">Connect</label>
                </div>
                <div className="field-checkbox">
                    <Checkbox inputId="method2" name="method" value="Delete" onChange={onMethodChange} checked={methods.indexOf('Delete') !== -1} />
                    <label htmlFor="method2">Delete</label>
                </div>
                <div className="field-checkbox">
                    <Checkbox inputId="method3" name="method" value="Get" onChange={onMethodChange} checked={methods.indexOf('Get') !== -1} />
                    <label htmlFor="method3">Get</label>
                </div>
                <div className="field-checkbox">
                    <Checkbox inputId="method4" name="method" value="Head" onChange={onMethodChange} checked={methods.indexOf('Head') !== -1} />
                    <label htmlFor="method4">Head</label>
                </div>

            </div>

    )}
```

Comment: can you show your css to please - see how to create a [mcve] - as this seems to be just a styling issue, you just need your html and css

Comment: @Pete I added the style and code of my modal window to the condition

Comment: I removed the [tag:java] tag, because it doesn't have anything to do with Java.

Comment: @Павел Could you try to move the `<Checkbox>` elements *inside* the `<label>`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the div - parent of the checkboxes is a block level element. It should work, if you change it to be flex.

```
<div style={{display: "flex"}}>
  <Checkbox inputId="method1" name="method" value="Connect" onChange={onMethodChange} checked={methods.indexOf('Connect') !== -1} />
  <label htmlFor="method1">Connect</label>
</div>
```

#### Update.

Add space between the Checkbox and the label

1. Depending on how much space you need and the width of the div, you can  use

```
 <div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
 
 - - -
```

2. Set padding-right / margin-right on the outer most element in Checkbox
3. Set padding-left / margin-left on the label

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works, thanks. Perhaps you can still tell me how to make a space between the checkbox and the label

Answer (score 1):

You can convert checkboxes to inline elements:

```
<div>
  <Checkbox style={{display: "inline"}} inputId="method1" name="method" value="Connect" onChange={onMethodChange} checked={methods.indexOf('Connect') !== -1} />
  <label htmlFor="method1">Connect</label>
</div>
```

or, use flex layout:

```
<div style={{display: "flex"}}>
  <Checkbox inputId="method1" name="method" value="Connect" onChange={onMethodChange} checked={methods.indexOf('Connect') !== -1} />
  <label htmlFor="method1">Connect</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but my modal window completely disappears with these changes))

Comment: I noticed that you are using react, so the style is written differently. I have modified the code and it may work fine.